# Google Maps location with different address onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I written some HTML for Google Maps location.

In the page I create two different addresses with buttons as `View on map` so when I click the button it redirects to another page where it should get the Google Map location by using the address only.

But, on the result page it shows me the Google Map location of only one address. The script is working there with any addresses, but I need it to work with the `onClick` event.

Here are the links:

*(this page link will show you two address with their own buttons)*

http://happy1.studioscue.in/hello.html

...and the other link will show you the result page where the Google location should display. Only one Google Map of Australia and that's because I use there Australia under body tag & the page. The link is:

http://happy1.studioscue.in/google.html

Comment: you never passed any map-parameters or co-ordinates to google.html

Comment: The links are dead in this question, a risk for any question that relies on external links. This does mean it needs to be closed. Please try to keep your questions as self-contained as possible, to limit the amount of closure and deletion required.

Answer (score 1):

As @Devs mentioned in a comment above, you have to pass some map parameters (place name or coordinates) to google.html page. I modified your hello page to:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <address>
            Sector 75-Noid...
        </address>
        <a href="google.html?q=France"><button type="button">view on map</button></a>

        <address>Delhi</address>
        <a href="google.html?q=Delhi"><button type="button">view on map</button></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, google.html links now have "q" query string parameter, which will be used in google.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/extras/coffee-script.js"></script>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>Welcome to JS Bin</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Doppio+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("address").each(function() {                         
                    var embed ="<iframe width='425' height='350' frameborder='0' scrolling='no'  marginheight='0' marginwidth='0'   src='https://maps.google.com/maps?&amp;q="+ encodeURIComponent( getParameterByName('q') ) +"&amp;output=embed'></iframe>";
                    $(this).html(embed);       
                });

                function getParameterByName(name, url) {
                    if (!url) {
                        url = window.location.href;
                    }
                    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
                    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
                    results = regex.exec(url);
                    if (!results) return null;
                    if (!results[2]) return '';
                    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <address>Australia</address>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can try the working demo [here](http://mobilestudio.pl/hello.html)

Comment: hello, i checked your demo but on the first the address is sector 75-noida but on click it display france map location & i see in the code you write code for both 2 addresses but there will be lots of address so for all of them  will have to write that code in ancher tag manually? & is it will work with dynamic address   please reply me asap thanks & Regards